# Using Listeners within a Listener efficiently?

Tags: java, javafx

If I have more than one `TextField` in the context of a form, how can a 'submit' button remain disabled until a **arbitrary number** of `TextFields` are not blank?

This can be done simply if only one `TextField` is present with a `ChangeListener` on the text field but how could it be implemented for *x* `TextField`'s? 

Where *x* is a number > 1.

**One TextField Example**

The `.setDisable()` method of the button is implemented with a `ChangeListener` on the `TextField` checking if the field is empty.

This behaves:

- Button is *disabled* when the textfield is empty
- Button is *enabled* when the textfield contains something

... as expected.

If the same Listener is utilised with both fields (as below), they behave as if they were independent of each other.
**eg.** If either one contains something, then the button is enabled:

```
public void someMethod(){
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.APPLY, ButtonType.CANCEL);

    TextField textField1 = new TextField();
    textField1.setPromptText("field1");
    TextField textField2 = new TextField();
    textField2.setPromptText("field2");


    // add fields to gridpane
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.add(textField1,0,0);
    gridPane.add(textField2,0,1);

    // add grid to dialog pane
    dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(gridPane);

    Node applyButton = dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.APPLY);
    applyButton.setDisable(true);

    ChangeListener<String> myChangeListener = new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            applyButton.setDisable(newValue.trim().isEmpty());
        }
    };

    textField1.textProperty().addListener(myChangeListener);
    textField2.textProperty().addListener(myChangeListener);

    dialog.showAndWait();
}
```

This is also the case, if independent Listeners are added to each field using the same process:

```
textField1.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        applyButton.setDisable(newValue.trim().isEmpty());
    }
});


textField2.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        applyButton.setDisable(newValue.trim().isEmpty());
    }
});
```

---

**Multiple Attempt**
One solution for multiple is to simply 'layer' the listeners within in each other. This behaves as intended, with both TextFields having to contain *something* before the button is enabled.

```
    textField1.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            // add listener to textField 2
            textField2.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                    applyButton.setDisable(newValue.trim().isEmpty());

                    // ... add listener to textField x
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This process seems very inefficient!
What if I have 20 `TextFields`? Should I be 'layering' 20 deep?

Is this the only way to do this? If not, how can the process be more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add extra listeners inside other listeners - you want to observe the change regardless of whether a previous change happened or not.

Instead, you must check for the validity of the entire input (*all* text-fields are non-empty) with each change. This can be done fairly generically by passing all `TextField`s to one method:

```
private void setButtonTextFieldListeners(Button button, TextField... textFields) {
    ChangeListener<String> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        for (int i=0; i<textFields.length; i++) {
            if (textFields[i].getText()==null || textFields[i].getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                button.setDisable(true);
                return;
            }
        }
        button.setDisable(false);
    }
    for (TextField textField : textFields) {
        textField.textProperty().addListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can build a `BooleanExpression` by `and`ing all of your conditions, then binding the button's `disable` property to its negation:

```
BooleanExpression b = textField1.textProperty().isNotEmpty()
                  .and(textField2.textProperty().isNotEmpty())
                  .and(...);
// b is True if and only if ALL text fields are not-empty. The button should be disabled when this ISN'T the case (enabled when b is True).
button.disableProperty().bind(b.not());
```

Comment: I'd go for the reactive approach using the `BooleanExpression`. If you use `isEmpty()`, then you also don't have to negate the binding. Moreover, one can easily extend this solution to achieve more advanced form validation.

Comment: @beatngu13 - it is important to note that if you use `isEmpty` instead of `isNotEmpty` you must also change all `and`s to `or`s.